# How to make iteration of array perfectly which is inside Object such that it doesn't give error on browser refresh in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, redux-toolkit

Problem: **I want to access images array each image for single product. Main issue is iteration is working fine but when browser is refreshed it gives error**
**This my own local api file i made in reactjs i am trying to make e-commerce store for portfolio**

```
{
        id:11,
        name:"Fresco Dining Set",
        price: 178000,
        status:"In Stock",
        totalquantity: 1,
        totalprice: 178000,
        description:"Contemporary design Gold-sharp black legs which complement Enza's custom design",
        category:{
            id:2,
            name:"Chair"
        },
        images:[
            "images/chairs/fresco_dining_set.jpg",
            "images/chairs/fresco_chair.jpg",
            "images/chairs/fresco_dining_table.png",
        ],
        rating:4.0,
        createdate:"2023-03-28"
    },
```

Problem: **I want to access images array each image for single product.**

```
images:[
            "images/chairs/fresco_dining_set.jpg",
            "images/chairs/fresco_chair.jpg",
            "images/chairs/fresco_dining_table.png",
        ],
```

This is my code right. I am trying to make single product detail.

```
const SingelProduct = () => {
  const dispatch=useDispatch();
  const {singleData}=useSelector(state=>state.api);
    const param=useParams();
    let pageid=Number(Object.values(param));
    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(fetchData(data)) 
        
      dispatch(setDetails(pageid))
  },[data])
  
  return (
    <>
        <div className="singleproduct">
                <div className="singlecontainer">
                         <div className="slideimg">
                          <img src={`/${singleData.images}`}/>
                         </div>         
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Is it good practice to place array in objects like this?

Comment: No ,you can't have multiple href on a img. You'll need to map and render a img for each link you have

Comment: yes i know i was just showing where i am doing it.

Answer (score 1):

As you have an array of images, you need to return several  such as:

```
<div className="slideimg">
    {singleData?.images?.map((imgSrc) => <img key={imgSrc} src={`/${imgSrc}`}/>)}
</div>
```

Comment: i have tried it but it gives where error when browser is refreshed although i am getting data still it gives:  Error:SingelProduct.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').  I also tried Object.values many other things but getting error on refresh

Comment: I suppose it is because you don't have the value at the first render, you can replace by `singleData?.images?.map`

Comment: @MoeezAHmad this could be because initially data might not be available.  Try `singleData?.images?.map`  or validate using `Array.isArray(singleData.images)`

Comment: thanks! bros!  this way worked:  '**{singleData.images?singleData.images.map(cur=>{
                            return (<img key={cur} src={`/cur`}/>)
                          }):"null"}**

Comment: but there is one more problem i can see img only showing alt text although i am using **<img src={`/${cur}` />**  i am using react router

Comment: Your images are stored in your backend? Maybe you have to concatenate your back url and the url of your image?

Comment: sorry i missed `/${cur}` i was using `/cur` lke this in url thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your method is working fine before browser refresh and it's giving error on browser refresh just like **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')** then you can use this method:

```
{singleData.images?singleData.images.map(cur=>{
     return (<img key={cur} src={`/cur`}/>)
 }):"null"}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use the map function to iterate over the images array and render them.

```
{singleData.images.map((image, index) => (
              <img key={index} src={`/${image}`} alt={`Product Image ${index + 1}`} />
            ))}
```